# Fastest way to convert one encoding to another

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, encoding, utf-8

So I'm reading a file which could be encoded in any encoding. But for this example lets say UTF-16. I need to read the file in BYTES (So using `FileStream`, not `StreamReader`), AND in chunks of 1MB, and then convert the UTF-16 byte buffer into a UTF8 byte buffer.

What I'm doing right now:

```
char[] charBuffer = new char[bufferSize];
Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(utf16Buffer, 0, read, charBuffer, 0);
byte[] utf8Array = new byte[Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(charBuffer, 0, charsRead)];
int numBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(charBuffer, 0, charsRead, utf8Array, 0);

//Do something with utf8Array
//This is what Encoding.Convert does in the background.
```

This isn't actually that slow, but I was wondering if there was a faster way. Thanks.

Comment: There is always a faster way. The question you need to think about is if this is *fast enough for you*?

Comment: You're right. It is probably fast enough for me. However, I was wondering if I was doing something really stupid (like performing an extra conversion between the bytes). But, It would be nice if there was a way to do this faster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a faster way. You can use multiple threads to process your chunks. To avoid ruining the order for the buffers, you need to pass on the index of the buffer to each thread, and have them edit the same collection using that thread.

Comment: How would I go about reading the same file from multiple threads?

Comment: Well, i was not referring to that. I thought you were talking about the encoding. I was making an implementation right now.

Comment: It took so long.. but i tested an implementation. It is so complicated and i still did not get it right. Is was just slightly faster. There really is no benefit in doing this.

Comment: What I have is a FileStream to read bytes. Then, if the file is UTF8, I directly add the data to my "collection". If it's a different encoding, then I have to convert it to UTF8. I tested a producer-consumer pattern and only slightly improved performance for direct-utf8. I hope it will be better for a UTF-16 to UTF8 conversion.